# basic json_encode and jquery multiple values

Tags: php, jquery, json

This is my 3rd jquery script and I'm not sure what I'm doing.

I want to read multiple json values from 3 different queries.
My JSON is returning what I was expecting:

```
key
 1    ["value1"]
 2    ["value2"]
max   2101
total 22
```

I can read the first two values using somethin like this:

```
  ajax(                                      
   url: 'api.php, data: "", dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)        
    { 
      for (var i in rows)
      {
        var row = rows[i];
        value1 = row[0];
      }
```

How can I read the max value from the JSON? I tried thing like:

```
 $row[max], $row['max'], etc.
```

I'm reading the values with JavaScript

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear which technology are you are using to read these values? Javascript or PHP? I assume Javascript.

Comment: Have you tried just `rows.max`? I'm not sure what you're expecting `$row` to be as it's not defined anywhere in your given code

Answer (score 1):

`row.max` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript's [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp) function in your success handler.  It will convert your returned json text into a javascript object which you can then manipulate.  Something like:

```
success: function(data) {
         var returned_array = eval(data);

         //access values as if it were a regular javascript object
         alert(returned_array['max']);
         //OR
         alert(returned_array.max);
       }
```